# bash script called from ant not functioning

Tags: bash, ant

Firstly, the bash script works fine when I call it outside of ant. 
Here is the relevant part of the build.xml

```
<exec executable="/bin/bash" failonerror="true">
<arg value="-c" />
<arg value="script.sh" />
</exec>
```

Here is the relevant line in the bash script (script.sh):

```
nc -l 8044 | tee ./nc-out.txt &
```

When I call script.sh from bash, the contents of nc-out.txt get populated with the data sent to port 8044.

I require the ampersand there.

When the shell script is called from ant, it seems as if nc-out.txt is created, but stays empty.

A normal redirect such as:

```
nc -l 8044 > nc-out.txt &
```

Also does not work..

Any insight would be useful!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the same issue as your [previous question](http://superuser.com/q/438861/78905)?

Comment: Clearly different, started a new post because it seems to be related to ant.

Comment: Ah ok. If it's not the stdin issue, my guess would be [buffering](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009), but if ant is somehow to blame I probably can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ant exec your command its standard input is by default not tied to anything, so `netcat` will exits right away when you connect to the listening process since there is nothing more to read from stdin.

Since you want to run it in the background I assume that you only want to achieve a one-way logging : you can add the `-d` parameter to netcat to tell him not to read from standard input:

*script.sh*

```
#/bin/bash
netcat -d -l 8044 > nc-out.txt &
```

Fully working with the following ant build file example :

*build.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="script" name="bleh">
    <target name="script">
        <exec executable="/bin/bash" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-c" />
            <arg value="./script.sh" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: @GregorioDiStefano I added my full code example, and it works like a charm for me. Running `ant` in the build directory leaves the `nc` process in the background and I can successfully connect to it and see the output in the *nc-out.txt* file, even when no TTY is attached to the background `nc` anymore.

Comment: @GregorioDiStefano - you already tried the `-d` option?  You didn't state that in your question.  Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11119841/edit) with all relevant tests you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `spawn="true"` to your [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to give the background process you are creating its own life.